# Design pattern on iterating over list of classes implementing interface

Tags: list, design-patterns, chain

When I have a list of validation classes implementing an interface injected into a service for validating a request Object , what kind o pattern is this if I iterate over this list and call the method validate of each one?  All the validation classes validate something

- Is some kind of chain pattern?

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern

Comment: There are two kinds of validation: 1. the check for a valid state and 2. the process of make something valid. What is your task?

Comment: I didnt mean validation fot the pattern, it was just an example. I meant some classes that implement an interface and dont know eath other and execute all of them some kind of business logic, it can be validation or doing whatever

Answer (score 0):

No. Assuming you have a class Council

```
@Service
public class Council {
  @Inject
  private Councillor[] council;
  public boolean getConsensus(Act purpose) {
    for(Councillor member: council) {
      if (member.vetoes(purpose)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

This is **not** a chained because the elements have no responsibility for their chained neighbour. Here you have a stacktrace that returns to the very-same execution of the method getConsensus after every veto-call in a loop.

But an chain-pattern delegate the execution from Councillor to Councillor and let the stacktrace grow, one trace-line for every Councillor. If you have 200 Councillors your stacktrace will be 200 traces larger.